# simple background: tiling an image in a div

Tags: html, css, tiling

I am trying to do the simplest thing possible: tile a div with a subtle patterns background. I'm not new to code, but have never done this before.  I have searched everywhere- simple examples posted by others do not work.  Clearly there is a reason.

html:

```
<div id="text3">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#text3  
{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background-image: url ("green_cup.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

I have searched extensively and this method seems to work for everyone but me. Why is this code not applying a tiled pattern as a background to my '`?

Comment: Is the problem that the image is showing as a background but not repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to hate me for this, but it would have worked if you had just got rid of the space between url and (

`url ("` would become `url("`

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7AYt8/

Comment: arrg  don't hate ya- Luv ya!   the answers always in the code, right?

Comment: @innervibrance, if the answer is correct can you please mark it so :)

Comment: and how do I mark it as answered?  Sorry but the interface is not providing this answer.....